# I'm having problem using some data from an API

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, axios

I'm creating a simple full-stack CRUD app, using spring boot & react.js, but I'm having problems implementing the PUT request. All the CRUD operations works fine, I tested them with Postman.

Function I have done, using axios :

```
updateEmployee(employee, id){
        return axios.put(API+"/"+id, employee);
}
```

Method in spring boot :

```
@PutMapping("/employees")
public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
     employeeServices.save(employee);
     return employee;
}
```

Errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8090/employeeapi/employees/15' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

Comment: Did you allow localhost:3000 for CORS in your server side?

Comment: @SinanYaman yes, i used this : @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/"), in controller class

Comment: may you think that a problem can be the "id"? because I don't have put a id parameter at @RequestMapping and in update function in react, I call the axio.put(API+"/"+id)?